# How can I pass text or strings using SQLite JDBC?

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I am having this problem using JDBC.
I can create a table called food.db with text fields breakfast, lunch, dinner.  When I call the following....

```
          statement.executeUpdate("create table food (breakfast string, lunch string, dinner string)");
          breakfast = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What was your breakfast?");
            lunch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What was your lunch?");
            dinner = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What was your dinner?");
         statement.executeUpdate("insert into food values(\'"+breakfast+"\', \'"+lunch+"\' ,\'"+dinner+"\')");
```

That last statement, however, results in an error.  For whatever reason, it says that whatever I type in for "breakfast" (for example, oatmeal) is not a column, even though I know that I can use SQLite's syntax in this way to update columns.

Also I have checked the argument to executeUpdate(), and the syntax with single quotes and everything matches up...I have tried text and string column fields, get the same error for both.

Comment: Please check updated answer. You're escaping single quotes which isn't required.

Comment: Please use `PreparedStatement` with a parameterized query instead of concatenating user input into a query. You are currently open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

change `string` to `VARCHAR(SIZE)` OR `TEXT`

```
 statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE food (breakfast VARCHAR(25), lunch VARCHAR(25), dinner VARCHAR(25))");
 String breakfast = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What was your breakfast?");
 String lunch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What was your lunch?");
 String dinner = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What was your dinner?");
 statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO food (breakfast, lunch , dinner) VALUES ('"+breakfast+"', '"+lunch+"' ,'"+dinner+"')");
```

Comment: Yes this worked, thank you!  Is there any reason why I could not just skip the `(breakfast,lunch,dinner)` part after `food`?

Comment: in your case there are only three field so it does'nt matter you put (breakfast,lunch,dinner) part after food ....you can simply write it as statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO food VALUES ('"+breakfast+"', '"+lunch+"' ,'"+dinner+"')");

Comment: Ok thats what I thought I was doing before, but either way, thanks!

Comment: @SaulBrodsky You were escaping `'` with ``\`` which wasn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CREATE TABLE to

```
statement.executeUpdate("create table food (breakfast text, lunch text, dinner text)");
```

Your INSERT INTO statement is escaping single `'` quotes which isn't required. Change to

```
statement.executeUpdate("insert into food values('"+breakfast+"', '"+lunch+"' ,'"+dinner+"')");
```

There's no `string` data type in SQLite but it doesn't give an error because SQLite's SQL isn't strongly typed. The column affinity takes over and treats any unknown data type as NUMERIC. Better switch the column data type to TEXT or VARCHAR.